# Android: Can't check whether a string variable is null or not. How to check if a string variable is null or not?

Tags: java, string

I can't check whether a string is empty or not coming from rest service as input stream which then I am changing into string for parsing.

```
public boolean isNullorEmpty(String string)
  {
   if(string !=null || !string.isEmpty() || string.length()>0)
    return true;
   else
    return false;
 }
```

Please help me out to check if string is empty or not.

Comment: Since you are asking `android` question tag with android aswell

Comment: use StringUtils.isBlank() of commons apache

Answer (score 1):

The current problem in your code is that if the string you pass in argument is `null`, then`string !=null` is evaluated to `false`. Hence you'll try to evaluate `!string.isEmpty()` which will lead to a `NullPointerException`.

On the other hand if you pass a String that is not `null` (ex `""` or `"test"`), `string != null` is evaluated to true and hence you return `true`.

So to fix that you should, as the name of your method suggests, check if the String is null OR empty.

But since you're on android, don't reinvent the wheel and use [`TextUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence str)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

```
boolean isEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(myString);
```

> Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.

If you want to look about how is it implemented:

```
427     public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence str) {
428         if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
429             return true;
430         else
431             return false;
432     }
```

Comment: In both cases of string the function returning false. I dont know whats wrong with the code

Comment: @pankaj716 If you pass a `null` String, your method throws a `NullPointerException`. If you're not still convinced, just run this: http://ideone.com/5HFAx7. If you pass let's say the String `"test"`, `string !=null` is evaluated to true and hence you return true. This is simple logic, take a paper and see what your method does on some inputs. I updated my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: In my code it is not throwing any NullPointerException if i am checking  string is null or not. The code you have provided also not throwing any exception if i pass null. It is only returning flase in both cases.

Comment: @pankaj716 Oh sorry the link changed. See this:http://ideone.com/8mg7lA. Are you getting the text from an EditText? If so yes it can never be null (only empty) but if you want to check for null String too, your logic is flawed. Anyway even with non empty Strings it doesn't work as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this can be handled in plain java like:

And it can be written like:

```
public boolean isStringEmpty (){
    if(str ==null || str.isEmpty () || str.trim().equals("")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have solve my problem by just putting semicolon as an extra statement in scope of if condition